# FileManager.urls returning error

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager

I recently converted my project to Swift 3 and for the most part, it seems okay.  However, I receive an error related to FileManager that says:
"Use of instance member 'urls' on type 'FileManager'; did you mean to use a value of type 'FileManager' instead?"

This error makes no sense to me.  [Here is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOO2Q.png)

```
  static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager.urls(for: .DocumentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
```

Comment: why dont you upvote the accepted answer? this user took his time to help you!

Comment: I tried to upvote it, but it says users with less than 15 reputation can't change the publicly displayed score of answers (this is my first post, I don't have any reputation I guess)

Comment: and you are sure, that you are pressing the "up" arrow? 

Comment: I'm positive...

Comment: @DavidSeek ![look](https://postimg.org/image/3pz15f7cx/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the `urls` method on an instance of `FileManager`, not on the class itself.

Change it to:

```
FileManager.default.urls(...
```